# jQuery Ajax Second Request after Success

Tags: jquery, ajax

Pulling my hair out trying to make sense of this stuff.

Situation:
1. User clicks rating button (Rate function)
2. Calls Rate.php via ajax - updates #CountContainer with TotalCount (number of times the photo has been rated).
3. What I want to do now is... if TotalCount = 100, execute ImageStatus function (another ajax-driven function)

```
function Rate(PhotoID) {
    $.ajax({
    url: 'rate.php',
    data: 'photoID='+photoID,
        success: function(data) {
            $("#CountContainer").html(data);
        }
    });
}  


function ImageStatus(PhotoID) {
    $.ajax({
    url: 'imgStatus.php',
    data: 'photoID='+photoID,
        success: function(data) {
            $("#StatusContainer").html(data);
        }
    });
```

As always, I appreciate you programming wizards!

Comment: In  success of rating ajax what should you return? If the TotalCount is returned means it is easy to call if(TotalCount == 100){ImageStatus(PhotoID);} in the success of rating ajax

Comment: Does it have to be **exactly** 100 or **100 or more**? It's possible to go from 99 to 101 if someone else has also just rated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change `Rate(PhotoID)` to:

```
function Rate(PhotoID) {
    $.ajax({
    url: 'rate.php',
    data: 'photoID='+photoID,
        success: function(data) {
            $("#CountContainer").html(data);
            if(data == '100') {
                ImageStatus(PhotoID);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working. I tried replacing the ImageStatus function call to alert("HI") but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Then place `alert("HI");` just before `$("#CountContainer").html(data);` (inside `success` function). Is it alerts? If it is, check your server response `data` by `alert(data);` yo see if it is `100` or not. If you have ho `alert("HI");` at all, it means that your `AJAX` request wans'n succeed.

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
if (data == 100) {
    ImageStatus(PhotoId);
}
```

inside the success handler of the `Rate` function? Or is something going wrong when you try this?

Answer (score 0):

try rate function as following:

```
function Rate(PhotoID) {
  var count = $.ajax({
    url: 'rate.php',
    data: 'photoID='+photoID,
        success: function(data) {
            $("#CountContainer").html(data);
        }
    });
   count = count.responseText;
   if(count == 100) {
       ImageStatus(PhotoID);
   }
}
```